# Looking for feedback on a classing change making problem using tagged values

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

A am studying F# on my own.  I am working on a problem to make change in old British currency units.  Half the problem is to be solved with a triple, and then you are to solve to problem again using a record.  The good news is I have gotten my triple solution to work, and I am confident I can get the record variant working also.

HOWEVER, since I am working alone, and the book contains no solved examples, I am looking for feedback.  In particular, the way I solved this problem is VERY similar to the way I would solve it using a procedural/imperative language.  Also, the prompt asked me to use patterns, but I don't see anywhere my solution would benefit from using patterns.  In addition, I aske questions about a warning and an error in the code.

Code follows

```
(*
3.2 The former British currency had 12 pence to a shilling and 20 shillings to a pound. 
Declare functions to add and subtract two amounts, represented by triples (pounds, shillings, pence) of integers, 
and declare the functions when a representation by records is used. 
Declare the functions in infix notation with proper precedences, 
and use patterns to obtain readable declarations.

Hansen, Michael R.; Rischel, Hans. Functional Programming Using F# (p. 66). Cambridge University Press. Kindle Edition. 
*)

(*
 My strategy is to convert pounds, shillings, and pence to the smallest unit, pence, then rebuild a normalized form of 
 change from just pence.

 Addition and subtraction are done in Pence converted to int.
*)

type OldBritishCurrency = | Pound of int
                          | Shilling of int
                          | Pence of int

let pencePerShilling = 12
let shillingPerPound = 20
let pencePerPound = shillingPerPound * pencePerShilling

// OldBritishCurrency.Pence != int and I don't know how to overload an (int (Pence x)) cast yet
let penceToInt (Pence p) = p

(*
Ch03.fsx(87,39): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. 
    For example, the value 'Pence (_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

I am thinking of OldBritishCurrency as a type with subtypes Pound, Shilling, and Pence,
However, a tagged type is obviously NOT a subtype, at least not exactly.

The warning message and the question seem to assume the need for a pattern to ID the tag.

This function converts Pound * Shilling * Pence to Pence.
*)
let oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p) =
    Pence (bp * pencePerPound + s * pencePerShilling + p)

let penceToShillingsAndPence(Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p) =
    (Pound bp, Shilling (s + p / pencePerShilling), Pence (p % pencePerShilling))

let shillingsToPoundsAndShillings(Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p) =
    (Pound (bp + s / shillingPerPound), Shilling (s % shillingPerPound), Pence p)

//Converts Pence to Pound * Shilling * Pence in standard form
let penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency (Pence p) = 
        penceToShillingsAndPence(Pound 0, Shilling 0, Pence p)  |> shillingsToPoundsAndShillings
        
let (.+.) (Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p) (Pound bp', Shilling s', Pence p') =
    let a = penceToInt(oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p)) // don't know how to overload +
    let b = penceToInt(oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound bp', Shilling s', Pence p'))
    penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence (a + b))

let (.-.) (Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p) (Pound bp', Shilling s', Pence p') =
    let a = penceToInt(oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound bp, Shilling s, Pence p)) // don't know how to overload -
    let b = penceToInt(oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound bp', Shilling s', Pence p'))
    penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence (a - b))

// testing

oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound 2, Shilling 2, Pence 3)

penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence 507)

oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound 10, Shilling 10, Pence 0)

penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence 2520)

penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence 253)

//

oldBritishChangeToPence(Pound 0, Shilling 19, Pence 11)

penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence(507 + 239))

(Pound 2, Shilling 2, Pence 3) .+. (Pound 0, Shilling 19, Pence 11)

penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence(507 - 239))

(Pound 2, Shilling 2, Pence 3) .-. (Pound 0, Shilling 19, Pence 11)

penceToNormalizedOldBritishCurrency(Pence(239 - 507))

(Pound 0, Shilling 19, Pence 11) .-. (Pound 2, Shilling 2, Pence 3)

//

oldBritishChangeToPence(Shilling 0, Shilling 1, Pence 1)
(*
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException: The match cases were incomplete
at FSI_0053.oldBritishChangeToPence(OldBritishCurrency _arg1, OldBritishCurrency _arg2, OldBritishCurrency _arg3) 
in C:\Users\trent\Source\Repos\HansenAndRischelCh03\HansenAndRischelCh03\Ch03.fsx:line 0
at <StartupCode$FSI_0054>.$FSI_0054.main@()
Stopped due to error

So, if I don't use a pattern, I get a warning, but when I provide Shilling and Pound is expected, I get an error
similar to a type match error ... which is GOOD!  It's just what I want.

Can I ignore the previous warning?

And if I can protect myself with something akin to type checking, what is the pattern matching 
    the question wanted me to include?
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your basic representation of teh data is a bit confusing. You define `OldBritishCurrency` to be a discriminated union that can be either pounds, shillings or pence. However, you do not use it to represent data that can be specified in either of the three kinds of change. You typically want pounds *and* shillings *and* pence and this is better done with a tuple:

```
type OldBritishCurrency = int * int * int
```

However, I think your idea of converting money in pounds, shillings and pences to just pences works well. You can do this quite easily using the tuple representation:

```
let pencePerShilling = 12
let shillingPerPound = 20
let pencePerPound = shillingPerPound * pencePerShilling

let oldBritishToPence (bp, s, p) =
    (bp * pencePerPound + s * pencePerShilling + p)

let penceToOldBritish p =
    let s = p / pencePerShilling
    (s / shillingPerPound, s % shillingPerPound, p % pencePerShilling)
```

In this representation, you are losing some readability, because the tuple is just three unnamed integers. This is where a record would be much better:

```
type OldBritishCurrency = { Pounds:int; Shillings:int; Pence:int }
```

If you modify the above code to use this, you will get a nicer and more readable solution!